# How to write this three-liner as a one-liner?

Tags: scala

I like the way, you can write one-liner-methods in Scala, e.g. with `List(1, 2, 3).foreach(..).map(..)`.

But there is a certain situation, that sometimes comes up when writing Scala code, where things get a bit ugly. Example:

```
def foo(a: A): Int = {
  // do something with 'a' which results in an integer
  // e.g. 'val result = a.calculateImportantThings

  // clean up object 'a'
  // e.g. 'a.cleanUp'

  // Return the result of the previous calculation
  return result
}
```

In this situation we have to return a result, but can not return it directly after the calculation is done, because we have to do some clean up before returning.

I always have to write a three-liner. Is there also a possibility to write a one-liner to do this (without changing the class of `A`, because this may be a external library which can not be changed) ?

Comment: If the operations on 'a' are always the same, why not wrap them into a function?

Comment: in addition to Vinc' comment: *one-liners don't play well with imperative code*.

Comment: Your introductory example is wrong: you can't do `List(1, 2, 3).foreach(..).map(..)` because `foreach` returns `Unit`. Also I want to add to ziggystar's comment: hunting for one-liners while writing imperative code is just wrong and will get you nowhere, because it simply violates the essence of imperative programming paradigm.

Comment: You need some library for extending functions combination. Like PEAK library for python. I've searched for one and found none. May be you would be lucky

Comment: The cheeky answer to the question is to just use semicolons to cram it onto one line: `def foo(a : A): Int = { val result = a.calculateImportantThings; a.cleanup; result }`. I mean, that's what semicolons are for, right? To combine side-effecting actions by sequencing them.

Answer (score 9):

There are clearly side-effects involved here (otherwise the order of invocation of `calculateImportantThings` and `cleanUp` wouldn't matter) so you would be well advised to reconsider your design.

However, if that's not an option you could try something like,

```
scala> class A { def cleanUp {} ; def calculateImportantThings = 23 }
defined class A

scala> val a = new A
a: A = A@927eadd

scala> (a.calculateImportantThings, a.cleanUp)._1
res2: Int = 23
```

The tuple value `(a, b)` is equivalent to the application `Tuple2(a, b)` and the Scala specification guarantees that its arguments will be evaluated left to right, which is what you want here.

Comment: This is really one liner, not a workaround as others propose!

Comment: I vote this as "rather cryptic code"; relying on some pretty unimportant (and thus unknown) part of the scala specification.

Comment: @ziggystar You think evaluation order is an unimportant part of the Scala specification?!?

Comment: @ziggystar The one-liner would be `def foo(a:A):Int = (a.calculateImportantThings, a.cleanup)._1`. I don't consider this cryptic at all: the reader can clearly see that since ._1 is invoked immediately, the only reason to put the two values in a tuple in the first place is to perform both effects.

Comment: @MilesSabin All code I wrote up until know did not rely on evaluation order and I don't plan to write code that does in the near future. So to me, this detail has been unimportant. Indeed I paused a bit before writing "unimportant", as I meant unimportant to the majority of code written.

Comment: @ziggystar Well, yes, but this question inherently depends on evaluation order because it involves side-effects. As such pretending that side-effects aren't important is ... unwise.

Answer (score 7):

This is a perfect use-case for `try`/`finally`:

```
try a.calculateImportantThings finally a.cleanUp
```

This works because try/catch/finally is an *expression* in scala, meaning it returns a value, and even better, you get the cleanup whether or not the calculation throws an exception.

Example:

```
scala> val x = try 42 finally println("complete")
complete
x: Int = 42
```

Comment: Fascinating! I wouldn't consider this an abuse in the least, especially since you probably want to `a.cleanup` even if `a.calculateImportantThings` throws an exception. If anything, I'd say this use case is the very *reason* that try/catch/finally is an expression in Scala.

Comment: Dan, you are right, on reflection this is a *perfect* use-case for try/finally! Wording ajusted.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you want to use a kestrel combinator? It is defined as follows:

> Kxy = x

So you call it with the value you want to return and some side-effecting operation you want to execute.

You could implement it as follows:

```
def kestrel[A](x: A)(f: A => Unit): A = { f(x); x }
```

... and use it in this way:

```
kestrel(result)(result => a.cleanUp)
```

More information can be found here: [debasish gosh blog](http://debasishg.blogspot.de/2009/09/side-effects-with-kestrel-in-scala.html).

**[UPDATE]** As Yaroslav correctly points out, this is not the best application of the kestrel combinator. But it should be no problem to define a similar combinator using a function without arguments, so instead:

```
f: A => Unit
```

someone could use:

```
f: () => Unit
```

Comment: Well, it can be used here but it isn't the best application of the kestrel combinator, cause it's designed to return a value on which side-effects are executed, while it is needed to return a result of some of those side-effects.

Answer (score 5):

There is, in fact, a Haskell operator for just such an occasion:

```
(<*) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f a
```

For example:

```
ghci> getLine <* putStrLn "Thanks for the input!"
asdf
Thanks for the input!
"asdf"
```

All that remains then is to discover [the same operator in scalaz](http://scalex.org/?q=%3C%2a), since scalaz usually replicates everything that Haskell has. You can wrap values in `Identity`, since Scala doesn't have `IO` to classify effects. The result would look something like this:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def foo(a: A): Int = 
  (a.calculateImportantThings.pure[Identity] <* a.cleanup.pure[Identity]).value
```

This is rather obnoxious, though, since we have to explicitly wrap the side-effecting computations in Identity. Well the truth is, scalaz does some magic that *implicitly* converts to and from the Identity container, so you can just write:

```
def foo(a: A): Int = Identity(a.calculateImportantThings) <* a.cleanup()
```

You *do* need to hint to the compiler *somehow* that the leftmost thing is in the Identity monad. The above was the shortest way I could think of. Another possibility is to use `Identity() *> foo <* bar`, which will invoke the effects of `foo` and `bar` in that order, and then produce the value of `foo`.

To return to the ghci example:

```
scala> import scalaz._; import Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> val x : String = Identity(readLine) <* println("Thanks for the input!")
<< input asdf and press enter >>
Thanks for the input!
x: String = asdf
```

Comment: Let me take this opportunity to say I love your Haskell+Scala answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Test {
  def cleanUp() {}
  def getResult = 1
}

def autoCleanup[A <: Test, T](a: A)(x: => T) = {
  try { x } finally { a.cleanUp }
}  

def foo[A <: Test](a:A): Int = autoCleanup(a) { a.getResult }


foo(new Test)
```

You can take a look at [scala-arm](https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm) project for type class based solution.

Comment: He asked for a one liner, not for an auto cleanup solution.

Comment: He NEED an auto cleanup solution.

Comment: Where did he asked for it? In the example. What does it mean? That instead of `cleanUp` may be `anyOtherMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the chaining operation [`tap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#tap[U](f:A=%3EU):A) can be used to *apply a side effect* (in this case the cleanup of A) on any value *while returning the original value untouched*:

> def tap[U](f: (A) => U): A

---

```
import util.chaining._

// class A { def cleanUp { println("clean up") } ; def calculateImportantThings = 23 }
// val a = new A
val x = a.calculateImportantThings.tap(_ => a.cleanUp)
// clean up
// x: Int = 23
```

In this case `tap` is a bit abused since we don't even use the value it's applied on (`a.calculateImportantThings` (`23`)) to perform the side effect (`a.cleanUp`).